# Net::HTTP very slow on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04

We just recently upgraded from Debian Lenny to Ubuntu 12.0.4 on one of our Ruby application servers, and are seeing some very slow HTTP POSTs using Net::HTTP.

When I run a POST using Net::HTTP to a service running on localhost on the Lenny machine the response time is 6-9ms.

When I run the same Net::HTTP POST on any version of ruby on our Ubuntu machine I get a response time of 240ms+.

However, when I run that POST again through curl I get a 6-9ms repsonse time on ubuntu.

Anyone know how this would happen? We're using ruby 1.9.3 installed via RVM, but 2.0.0 has the same problem.

Comment: Did you recompile Ruby after upgrading the OS?

Comment: Yeah ruby was built after the OS upgrade.